# Kotlin Coroutines: How lightweight are Kotlin Job() objects? Can I leave finished Jobs in a HashMap?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm writing a simple class which can download images and write them to a cache. If one url is requested twice, any existing download job for this file should be cancelled.

Can I just use a HashMap and store the running Jobs? Or will this produce memory leaks, if finished Jobs are still in the HashMap?

Here are some snippets from my code:

**HashMap:**

```
val jobs = HashMap<Int, Job>()
```

**Cache Fun:**

```
fun doCache(url: String) {
    val hash = url.hashCode()
    jobs[hash]?.cancel()
    val job = Job()
    jobs[jobTag] = job

    val cached = File(cacheDir, "img-$hash.dat")
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job).launch {
        download(url, cached)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question: hashes may collide, so you probably want to use the url as key of the jobs map.

Comment: @blubb You are absolutely right. The default hash function from Java/Kotlin is far from good. In my use case collisions won't be a big deal, though. Also, I'm using a `SparseArray<Job>` in my application, because `HashMap<Int,...` is not very efficient.